# pass global variable between two function on zf2 controller

Tags: variables, frameworks, zend-framework2, global

I should change on zf2 controller a variable global. In practice, I'd like a function to insert the value in the global variable and another function prints the value of the variable. for example:

```
protected $variablename;

public function setAction()
{

      $this->variablename = "hi friends!";

}

public function getAction()
{

      var_dump($this->variablename);

}
```

In this example, when I print the variable I always get NULL.
Any suggestions? tnx
simone

Comment: Hi Simone, there are multiple ways of parsing variables around. It would be nice if you could make your purpose clear of why you want to do this and extend your example. In this way you can get a better advise, but with the above example it just looks like we need to pass a variable in the controller so you could make a property in your controller with a simple get and set method like you illustrate already.

Answer (score 1):

indirectly you can't because of the lifecircle in a zend/php request. after you set up your variable in `actionA` the variable is reseted if you request `actionB`

if you want to set your variabel data in `actionA` and make the data present in `actionB` you need a persistent save storage (like a `db`, `cookie` or `session`. otherwise it is only possible to `forward` the current request to another request in your controller. then have a look at the `forward` controller helper in zend.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-forward

//edit after comment

you can use a `session` in zend like this

**set session**

```
$session = new Zend\Session\Container('base');
$session->offsetSet('someSettings', 'someValue');
```

**get session**

```
$session = new Zend\Session\Container('base');
if( $session->offsetExists('someSettings') )
{
    $someSettingValue = $session->offsetGet('someSettings');
}
```

Comment: hi, tnx about your answer. how can i use session o cookie?

Comment: May accept this as your answer if this was what you are looking for